# "Missing 1 required positional argument: 'resp'" when invoking Falcon resource responder that has a 'self' argument

Tags: python-3.8, falconframework, waitress

I am developing a WSGI application on Windows. I use peewee (which is supposedly unrelated) and:

```
falcon==2.0.0
waitress==1.4.3
```

I have the following code in my `resources.py`:

```py
from models import Board

class BoardResource:
    def on_get_collection(self, req, resp):
        resp.media = Board.select()

    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        code = req.get_param('code')
        resp.media = Board.get_by_id(code)
```

I have the following code in my `app.py`:

```py
import falcon
import models
from resources import BoardResource

def init():
    models.init()
    api = falcon.API()
    api.add_route('/boards', BoardResource, suffix='collection')
    api.add_route('/board', BoardResource)
    return api

api = init()
```

I start the app with this command: `waitress-serve app:api`. When I request `/boards` from the API, I get this error:

```
ERROR:waitress:Exception while serving /boards
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\pepsiman\.virtualenvs\hsech-api\lib\site-packages\waitress\channel.py", line 349, in service
    task.service()
  File "c:\users\pepsiman\.virtualenvs\hsech-api\lib\site-packages\waitress\task.py", line 169, in service
    self.execute()
  File "c:\users\pepsiman\.virtualenvs\hsech-api\lib\site-packages\waitress\task.py", line 439, in execute
    app_iter = self.channel.server.application(environ, start_response)
  File "c:\users\pepsiman\.virtualenvs\hsech-api\lib\site-packages\falcon\api.py", line 269, in __call__
    responder(req, resp, **params)
TypeError: on_get_collection() missing 1 required positional argument: 'resp'
```

I decided to remove the `self` argument from the definiton of `on_get_collection` and the error was gone. I know that `self` must be there and have no idea why it doesn't work like that. Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem myself: when calling `api.add_route` the responder class must indeed be instantiated, thus the following lines:

```py
api.add_route('/boards', BoardResource, suffix='collection')
api.add_route('/board', BoardResource)
```

need to be modified like this:

```py
api.add_route('/boards', BoardResource(), suffix='collection')
api.add_route('/board', BoardResource())
```

Of course it works without removing the `self` argument from the definitions.

I hope this silly mistake of mine will help someone fix theirs.